# Validando Data de nascimento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,
Estou tentando validar data de nascimento menor a 15 anos utilizando a seguinte regra:

1- Se o usuário entrar com a data de nascimento, verificar se o dia, mês e ano q o usuário digitou, corresponde a menor  que 15 anos, se sim, o botão será ocultado.

Inserir a seguinte função abaixo:

```
function calculaIdade(dobString) {

var data_nasc = document.getElementById('data_cri').value.split("/");
var verifica = data_nasc[2]+data_nasc[1]+data_nasc[0];

var dob = new Date(dobString);
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var birthdayThisYear = new Date(currentYear, dob.getMonth(), dob.getDate());
var verifica = currentYear - dob.getFullYear();

alert(verifica); //mostra a idade
alert(currentYear); // mostra o ano

alert(birthdayThisYear);

if (verifica >= 15 && currentYear < birthdayThisYear ){
    //alert('pode');
    document.getElementById('mostravid').style.display = "block";
} else {
    //alert('nao pode');
    document.getElementById('mostravid').style.display = "none";

}

if (verifica == ''){
    document.getElementById('mostravid').style.display = "none";

  }
}

<input type='text' name='data_cri' id='data_cri' value='<?=$data_cri?>' size='12' maxlength='10' onkeyup='formataData(this,this.value);' onblur='return calculaIdade(this.value)'>
```

Por enquanto está funcionando validando apenas por ano, gostaria que validasse da seguinte maneira:

o usuário nasceu 21/09/2000 porém, a idade dele é de 14 anos utilizando essa função acima, amanha é dia 22/09, o usuário entrara com os dados 22/09, a função vai calcular 15 anos, ok .

Gostaria ajuda de vocês para calcular dessa forma.

Obrigado

Comment: Temos um problema no cálculo quando consideramos o ano bissexto... se fizer a diferença pelo tempo exato passado o dia antes do aniversário pode ser considerado como ok..

Comment: tem algum exemplo ai ?

Comment: Caso,queira agilizar seu trabalho :http://bit.ly/1efORk3 ou http://bit.ly/1KqRCR8 esta framework.

Comment: Obrigado pelo link e pelas dicas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galera, deu certo ... 
tive que utilizar ajax e php por questões de segurança, segue o script para quem quiser reaproveitar.

```
 //Data de nascimento
$data_cri = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_POST['data_cri'])));   

// data atual
$dt_fim = date('Y-m-d'); 

if (date('Y') - substr($data_cri,0,4) < 15){
        $date = str_replace('-', '/', $data_cri);
        echo "<div><h4>Data ".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))." fora do intervalo. <br> Menor que 15 anos não pode ser cadastrado!<h4> </div>"; 

}

// diferenca entre duas datas
if( isset($data_cri) && $data_cri!="" && isset($dt_fim) && $dt_fim!="") {
    $data_cri = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data_cri);
    $dt_fim = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dt_fim);

    if ((int)$dt_fim->diff($data_cri)->format('%y') >=15){
        echo "<div align='center'><input type='submit' value='Prosseguir'></div>";
        echo "<div align='center'><h3>Idade: ".(int)$dt_fim->diff($data_cri)->format('%y').' anos<h3></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ajax pra calcular data com valores que já estão na tela? Quais questões de segurança?

Comment: Estava ocultando uma div quando a idade era menor que 15 anos, sendo assim, se o usuário malicioso inspecionava o elemento, ele mesmo poderia alterar a propriedade para display='block' nesse caso o botão seria habilitado e ele conseguiria prosseguir, por isso que criei a chamada ajax, abs

Comment: Cara, nunca delegue as validações apenas à interface com o usuário. Suponho que uma validação na ação do botão seria menos complexa e menos custosa à navegação e ao sistema do que fazer requisições adicionais ao servidor. Você também pode remover o elemento via JavaScript, evitando a possibilidade de se exibir o botão em casos inválidos. E o que acontece se o usuário tentar submeter os dados com o JavaScript desativado ou através de um batch?

Answer (score 2):

uma solução contando os milisegundos

```js
//define as duas datas base...
var actualDate = new Date();
//validando 25/09/2000 que ainda nao completou 15 anos
var birthDate = new Date("2000", "8", "25", "0", "0", "0");

// pega o milisegundo de cada uma
var actualMili = actualDate.getTime();
var selectMili = birthDate.getTime();

// 15 anos em milisegundos
var timeToTest= 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 15; //15 anos em mili segundos...

//faz a diferença entre as datas e o tempo calculado
if( ( actualMili -  selectMili) >= timeToTest){
  document.body.textContent = "Pessoa com mais de 15 anos";
}
else{
  document.body.textContent = "Pessoa com menos de 15 anos";
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou h3nr1ke, qualquer data que eu insiro mostra que a  Pessoa com mais de 15 anos ...

Comment: Opa... como vc está inserindo as datas, lembrando que o mês deve ser colocado como número de 0 a 11, se vc rodar o código como está e colocar o ano de 2001 por exemplo, tem de mostrar com menos de 15 anos... lembrando o lance do ano bissexto que ainda permanece neste exemplo...

Comment: @hulckb coloquei o teste [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/g33eo044/2/) dá uma olhada

Comment: @h3nr1ke, movi o seu exemplo para o corpo da sua pergunta.

Comment: show @TobyMosque, realmente só compliquei separando, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

você pode simplesmente adicionar 15 anos a data atual.

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
var nascimento = document.getElementById("nascimento");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");

var mensagemErro = function (event, input, mensagem) {
  //input.setCustomValidity(mensagem);
  alert(mensagem);
  event.preventDefault();
}

formulario.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  var data = nascimento.value;
  //nenhuma data informada
  if (!data) {
    return mensagemErro(event, nascimento, "Campo nascimento não informado");
  }

  //O browser não realizou a conversão de forma nativa
  if (!(data instanceof Date)) {
    data = data.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    data = Date.parse(data);
    if (!isNaN(data)) {
      data = new Date(data);
    }
  }

  //a data informada não é valida
  if (!data) {
    return mensagemErro(event, nascimento, "Campo nascimento não é valido");
  }

  var atual = new Date();
  data.setFullYear(data.getFullYear() + 15);  

  //menor de 15 anos.
  if (data > atual) {
    return mensagemErro(event, nascimento, "Nascimento posterior a 15 anos atrás");
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <input id="nascimento" type="date" />
  <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

No caso acima, estou usando um input do tipo date, então só preciso converter a data manualmente se a propriedade value não me retornar uma data.

Comment: esse script nao rodou TobyMosque ...,

Comment: @hulckb, estava se perdendo na exibição das mensagens, coloquei um alerta.

Comment: como seria no caso da entrada do ano dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: o script já trata este comportamento, por exemplo, se você abrir em um exemplo em um navegador que não tenha o `input:date` implementado (eg: Firefox), você vai poder digitar uma data no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`, neste caso ele vai entrar na condição `!(data instanceof Date)` e o algotimo `data.split('/').reverse().join('-')` irá converter `dd/MM/yyyy` em `yyyy-MM-dd` que é uma data valida no formato `ISO 8601`

Answer (score 1):

Crie um objeto data com a data de nascimento do usuário e uma outra data com a data corrente menos 15 anos. Se a data de nascimento do usuário for inferior a data corrente menos 15 anos o usuário tem menos de 15 anos.

```
function idadeMaiorQue(dataNascimento, idadeMinima) {
    var userDob = new Date(dataNascimento);
    var maxDob = new Date();

    maxDob.setFullYear(maxDob.getFullYear() - idadeMinima);

    return !(userDob < maxDob);
}
```